# Building gcc for x86_64: error

Tags: gcc, compilation, x86-64

I am trying to build gcc 4.3.2 from sources in my x86_64 system which has a 32 bit gcc installed ( older version) which don't support -m64 switch. When I try to configure, it succeeds without any error but 'make' is failing with following error.

> checking for suffix of object files...
>   configure: error: cannot compute
>   suffix of object files: cannot compile
>   See `config.log' for more details.

I tried setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH and LD_OPTIONS but couldn't make any headway. I'm not sure I am going in right direction. Any idea what could be the problem? If anyone of you have come across such problem earlier, please respond if you have any solutions.Thank you

Comment: Show your entire configure line, especially the values of `--build`, `--host`, and `--target`.

Comment: I am not specifying any of these as I want a native compiler for x86_64 in my 64 bit linux system. Problem is I have a 32 bit compiler which is installed, I am not sure how to get around this?

Comment: Since you are building with a 32-bit toolchain, the default values will not correctly build a native x86_64 gcc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will first need to install a 32-bit to 64-bit cross-compiler, because your 32-bit compiler can't create 64-bit object files. Or install a 64-bit (cross-)compiler and use that to build your native compiler.